# Angular directive removes ng-click functionality

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that is almost an exact copy of the old uiIf directive from the angular-ui project.

What is happening is that when I add my "restrict" directive, the button is successfully added/removed based upon what the user is authorized to do.

The problem is that the ng-click action no longer works. It doesn't call in to the controller's scope and trigger the function to be called. Does anyone see what might be causing my issue?

See: http://plnkr.co/edit/38UeVCCYkdzxBkxOLe5g?p=preview

```
<button restrict="'canPerformAction'" ng-click="action()">Action</button>

'use strict';
angular.module('directives.restrict', [])
.directive('restrict', function(_){
  return{
    transclude: 'element',
    prioriry: 1000,
    terminal: true,
    restrict: 'A',
    compile:  function(element, attr, transclude) {
      var user = { caps: [ 'canPerformAction', 'canDance', 'canWrite' ] };

      return function(scope, element, attr) {
        var childElement;
        var childScope;

        scope.$watch(attr.restrict, function(attributes) {
          if (childElement) {
            childElement.remove();
            childElement = undefined;
          }
          if (childScope) {
            childScope.$destroy();
            childScope = undefined;
          }

          if(_.intersection(user.caps, attributes.split(' ')).length > 0) {
            childScope = scope.$new();
            transclude(childScope, function(clone) {
              childElement = clone;
              element.after(clone);
            });
          }
        });
      };
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: The `transclude` argument to `compile` is deprecated (cf. http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) and is not aware of the correct outer scope, which might be why `action()` does not get triggered successfully.

Comment: I'm actually still using the 1.0.X branch of Angular...don't get me started on "why I am still doing this". But the 1.2.X still demonstrates my issue. I've updated the plnkr to reflect this.

Comment: You have probably figured this out by now, but in case you're still stuck, 'priority' is misspelled in your directive. Change it in the plunker and your ng-click function gets called.

Comment: I didn't even notice that! Ugh! If you want to "answer" the question I'll mark it as answered.